# Problem With Transformation of Coordinates

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, transformation

In S.L. Loney's book on Coordinate Geometry, he introduces the reader a way to switch from one origin of coordinates to another. The method he shows is: to change the origin to the point $(h,k)$ you must replace the quanitities of $x$ and $y$ with $x + h$ and $y + k$. However, using an online graphic calculator, the examples he shows don't seem correct to me. According to his method, say I want to change the origin of coordinates to the point $(2,2)$; so if I have the curve $y^2 = 4x$ referred to in previous coordinates, the new curve should be $(y + 2)^2 = 4(x + 2)$. However, when I check the online graphic calculator, the method has changed the origin to $(-2,-2)$, not $(2,2)$. Could someone explain what I am misinterpretting? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should state EXACTLY what Loney writes, because quite often questions like yours tend to be someone misstating what an author actually says. In this case, are you sure that what Loney says is equivalent to replacing the variables $x$ and $y$ in the pre-shifted equation with $x+h$ and $y+k$ to get the after-shifted equation, rather than the other way around? Useful Stack Exchange question: [How does one explain that transformations 'inside' a function operate in the opposite direction than intuition suggests?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/5614/745)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro "Let the coordinates of the new origin referred to the original axes be $h$ and $k$. Let P be any point in the plane of the paper, and let it's coordinates, referred to the original axes, be $x$ and $y$ and referred to the new axes let them be $x'$ and $y'$. The origin is therefore, transferred to the point $(h,k)$ when we substitute for the coordinates $x$ and $y$ the quantities $x' + h$ and $y' + k$".

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro he also appends an example in which he changes the origin to the point $(-2,3)$ for the equation $2x^2+4xy+5y^2-4x-22y+7=0$; the result he gets is $2x'^2+4x'y'+5y'^2-22=0$. However, when I check using the online graphing calculator Desmos, I see that it has actually shifted the origin to $$.

Comment: The key issue is that there is a difference between changing the specified coordinates of a point and what one does with the variables in an equation. Your confusion is that Loney is discussing the former, and you interpreted it as the latter. See the Stack Exchange question I cited. For example, if you want to subtract $2$ to $x$-coordinates and add $3$ to $y$-coordinates, then the variables in an equation get replaced with $x+2$ and $y-3.$ It **is** a bit confusing, so look at the answers in that Stack Exchange question I cited. But again, note that you were misstating what Loney says.

Comment: **(continued)** Of course, maybe Loney's exposition is written in such a way that it could be misinterpreted. I'd have to look at Loney's text to see whether his description is could be easily misinterpreted, but for a book with (I think) so many editions, I tend to doubt this. But maybe (as was typical of math texts at the time) it was written with the understanding that readers would be using the text in a classroom with a teacher providing necessary additional explanation and blackboard drawings and such.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I don't see how exactly I misinterpreted the text though. When Loney says "to change the origin to the point $(h,k)$ for curve (1)", I assume what he means is to move (1) as if $(h,k)$ was now the new origin. So if (1) was 5 units below the previous origin, it should now be 5 units below the new origin.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro (cont) because if an addition of units moves the curve left\down, and a subtraction move it up\right, why exactly would he say that he has shifted the origin to the point $(h,k)$, when he in fact has actually shifted it to $(-h,-k)$? What gets me confused is that in later chapters, he still writes as if the origin has been changed correctly. In some examples he shows a geometrical diagram of which point the origin has been shifted to, but to me that makes no sense.

Comment: I agree that Loney's description is not quite the same way one usually sees this done in school classes now (but it's not wrong, just approached in a slightly different way), so I've included a detailed elaboration of the Loney example. It helped that I didn't have anything pressing to do this afternoon :). When I wrote my earlier comments, I thought I was going to have some contract work to take care of (and thus not have time to actually write an answer), but that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s look at *Ex. 1* on p. 111 of [**The Elements of Coordinate Geometry**](https://archive.org/details/elementsofcoordi00lone/page/110/mode/2up) by Sidney Luxton Loney (1895), which is the example you bring up in your comments.

> Transform to parallel axes through the point $(-2,3)$ the equation $$2x^2 \; + \; 4xy \; + \; 5y^2 \; - \; 4x \; - \; 22y \; + \; 7 \; = \;0.$$

The original variables are $x,y$ and the new variables are $x',y'.$ Each point has both an $x,y$ coordinate description and an $x',y'$ coordinate description.

We want the new origin to be the point whose $xy$ description is given by $(x,y) = (-2,3).$ That is, we want $(x,y) = (-2,3)$ and $(x',y')=(0,0)$ to be descriptions of the **same point**. Since we want the coordinate changes to be “as simple as possible” to achieve this (here I'm using [hand-waving wording](https://www.quora.com/What-do-mathematicians-mean-by-hand-waving-and-why-is-it-important)), we do this as follows:

$$ \text{add} \; 2 \; \text{to} \;\; x=-2 \;\; \text{to get} \; x’=0$$
$$ \text{subtract} \; 3 \; \text{from} \;\; y=3 \;\; \text{to get} \; y’=0$$

That is, to get $x'$ we add $2$ to $x,$ and to get $y'$ we subtract $3$ from $y.$

$$ x' = x + 2 \;\;\; \text{or} \;\;\; x = x' - 2 $$
$$ y' = y - 3 \;\;\; \text{or} \;\;\; y = y' + 3 $$

Thus, given that $2x^2+4xy+5y^2-4x-22y+7=0$ is the $xy$-equation of the locus, then the $x'y'$-equation of the same locus is obtained by replacing $x$ with $x’-2$ and replacing $y$ with $y’+3.$ This gives

$$2(x'-2)^2 \; + \; 4(x'-2)(y'+3) \; + \; 5(y'+3)^2 \; - \; 4(x'-2) \; - \; 22(y'+3) \; + 7 \;\; = \;\; 0 $$

$$2(x'^2-4x'+4) + 4(x'y'+3x'-2y'-6) + 5(y'^2+6y'+9) - 4x' + 8 - 22y' - 66 + 7 \; = \; 0 $$

$$2x'^2-8x'+ 8 + 4x'y'+12x'-8y'-24 + 5y'^2+30y'+45 - 4x' + 8 - 22y' - 66 + 7 \; = \; 0 $$

$$2x'^2 + 4x'y' + 25y'^2 + (-8+12-4)x' + (-8+30-22)y' + (8-24+45+8-66+7) \;\; = \;\; 0 $$

$$2x'^2 \; + \; 4x'y' \; + \; 25y'^2 \; - \; 22 \;\; = \;\; 0 $$

Comment: thank you for an elaborate answer! When we were discussing the problem in the comments, it seems as though we were using different languages. It turns out that I have completely misinterpreted the notion "to shift the origin of coordinates to $(h,k)$". I thought it meant to displace the curve in such a way so that it is positioned to $(h,k)$ the same way it was positioned to the original origin. However, I now understood that what was meant is "to rewrite the equation of the curve through the perspective of the new origin". Hence our miscommunication. Thank you greatly!

Comment: @Camelot823: *rewrite the equation of the curve through the perspective of the new origin* --- Probably a better way of expressing this is that it's through the perspective of the new coordinate system. When you encounter polar coordinates, and maybe you already have, you'll have descriptions in $xy$-coordinates and in $r\theta$-coordinates, where $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$ (and the other way being $r=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $\theta = \arctan{\frac{y}{x}}),$ and other than the algebraic manipulations being different, what I did above carries over with almost no conceptual changes.

Comment: I've only ever used polar coordinates to find the angle $\theta$ that a line makes with the x-axis whenever the line is represented by a homogenous equation. (because then the $r$'s cancel out). If you don't mind me asking as a side-question: is there perhaps a better way of putting one's knowledge of polar coordinates to use?

Comment: @Camelot823: Polar coordinates in school level math is usually discussed only in the context of a different way (sometimes simpler, sometimes not) of graphs of curves (e.g. [conics](https://web.archive.org/web/20230708130611/https://www.math.uh.edu/~mmsosa/Math1330/Notes/conics.pdf)). However, later on they're used in multivariable calculus (U.S. 3rd semester calculus) for [evaluating certain definite double integrals](https://web.archive.org/web/20230708131015/https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/dipolarcoords.aspx) **(continued)**

Comment: and in physics for working with [central forces](https://web.archive.org/web/20230708131724/https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahad0/1302week3Polar08.pdf) (see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230708131724/https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahad0/1302week3Polar08.pdf) also -- a *central force* is a force [whose magnitude depends only on the distance from some fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_central-force_problem), and it is independent of direction (orbits of planets, satellite orbits, and the like are examples, **(continued)**

Comment: as well as [the hydrogen atom](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/517054), which serves as an approximation for certain atomic orbital features of all other atoms). There are two well-known 3-dimensional analogues of polar coordinates -- cylindrical coordinates and spherical coordinates, which most people will first encounter in multivariable calculus (U.S. 3rd semester calculus). And there are others . . . see [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_system) and [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates).

Comment: oh, thank you much for the extended dicussion! Really, everything you touched on is most interesting to me!